Faux Random Maze Generator
For a personal project, I've written a maze generator in Python that I will be using A* to navigate through (using C++). The biggest points of improvements I'm looking for are in the generation itself. This is labeled "faux" because after generating a valid path, the other paths are just randomly chosen, instead of purposefully creating more segments. The algorithm is as follows:

Find the direction of the end point
Pick a random direction that goes toward that end point
Repeat until we reach the end

I'm wondering if this is a common way of "pathfinding", and if there's any better algorithm to go about this. Also, I know the comments are extremely overbearing and unnecessary, but that's how I remember my thought process. Before pushing this to my GitHub repository, I'll remove the extraneous ones.
import random

OUTPUT_FOLDER = "mazes/"

def generate_maze(
        dimension: tuple[int, int],
        start: tuple[int, int] = (0, 0),
        end: tuple[int, int] = None
    ) -> list[list[int]]:
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Creates an n x m maze by choosing a random direction towards the
    endpoint until reaching it. Then, randomly creates path nodes to
    simulate a maze-like structure.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dimension - A `tuple` containing the (width, height) of the desired maze.
    start - An optional `tuple` starting point in the maze.
    end - An optional `tuple` ending point in the maze. `None` means the end point will be in the bottom-right corner.

    Returns
    -------
    A `list` of rows for the completed maze, `1` denoting walls and `0` denoting paths.
    """
    # Unpack width and height from tuple
    width, height = dimension
    # Initialize the maze array with all walls
    maze = [[1] * width for _ in range(height)]
    # Unpack the current position from the tuple
    current_position = start
    # If end was passed, us it. Else, bottom right index
    end_position = end if end else (width - 1, height - 1)
    # Add randomness to the maze
    count = 0
    # rx: random_x , ry: random_y
    while (rx := random.randint(0, width - 1), ry := random.randint(0, height - 1)):
        # If we already have a path here, skip this iteration
        if maze[rx][ry] == 0: continue
        # Set the random index to 0
        maze[rx][ry] = 0
        # If we met our quota for the number of random paths generated
        if count == (width * height) // 4: # 1/4 of the maze
            # Leave loop
            break
        # Increment the path count
        count += 1
    # Loop until we reach the end point
    while True:
        # If we reached it, break
        if current_position == end_position:
            break
        # Get the direction to the end point
        dx, dy = get_direction(current_position, end_position)
        # Randomly choose between x and y coordinates to modify
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            # Set the current position to 1 multiplied by the direction_x
            current_position = (current_position[0] + (1 * dx), current_position[1] + 0)
        else:
            # Set the current position to 1 multiplied by the direction_y
            current_position = (current_position[0], current_position[1] + (1 * dy))
        # Set the current position in the maze to 0 (path)
        maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1]] = 0
    # Set the start point to 'S'
    maze[start[0]][start[1]] = 'S'
    # Set the end point to 'E'
    maze[end_position[0]][end_position[1]] = 'E'
    # Return the generated maze
    return maze

def get_direction(current: tuple[int, int], end: tuple[int, int]) -> tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Calculates the current direction needed to reach the end point.

    Parameters
    ----------
    current - The current position of the path.
    end - The desired ending position of the path.
    
    Returns
    -------
    A tuple containing the multipliers needed to navigate to the end.
    """
    current_x, current_y = current
    end_x, end_y = end
    if current_x == end_x and current_y < end_y: # Down
        return (0, 1)
    if current_x < end_x and current_y == end_y: # Right
        return (1, 0)
    if current_x == end_x and current_y > end_y: # Up
        return (0, -1)
    if current_x > end_x and current_y == end_y: # Left
        return (-1, 0)
    if current_x < end_x and current_y < end_y: # Right Down
        return (1, 1)
    if current_x < end_x and current_y > end_y: # Right Up
        return (1, -1)
    if current_x > end_x and current_y < end_y: # Left Down
        return (0, 1)
    if current_x > end_x and current_y > end_y: # Left Up
        return (-1, -1)
    return (0, 0)

def print_maze(maze: list[list[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Prints a maze for debugging purposes.

    Parameters
    ----------
    maze - Generated maze to print.

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    for row in maze:
        print(row)

def write_to_file(maze: list[list[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Writes the dimensions of the maze on the first line, then
    the generated maze.

    Parameters
    ----------
    maze - List of lists representing the generated maze.

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    width, height = len(maze[0]), len(maze)
    with open(OUTPUT_FOLDER + "maze.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{width} {height}\n")
        for row in maze:
            f.write(f"{''.join(str(e) for e in row)}\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    maze = generate_maze((20, 20))
    write_to_file(maze)


Overview
There is a lot to like about this code:

Most of the code is well laid out, with consistent indentation and spacing.
The functions and most of the variables have meaningful names.
The docstrings are excellent.  They clearly describe the purpose
of the functions and detail the inputs and return values.  And they
are all consistent.  Nice attention to detail!
Usage of hints.

Comments
I realize you offered a couple disclaimers with respect to the comments,
but everything is fair game.  The comments in the generate_maze function
detract from the code readability.  This is one exception to the good
layout of the rest of the code.
It would help to have a blank line before and after the 2 while loops.
When you say:

I'll remove the extraneous ones.

I think you should keep fewer than half of the 20 comments in the function.
Naming
I understand the appeal of having short names for index variables
# rx: random_x , ry: random_y
while (rx := random.randint(0, width - 1), ry := random.randint(0, height - 1)):

But, if you feel the need to add a comment describing the vague names,
then it would be better just to use longer names such as one of these:
random_x
rand_x
x_rand

Then you don't need the comment.
Here is another example of a comment that can be avoided with a more specific function name:
    # Get the direction to the end point
    dx, dy = get_direction(current_position, end_position)

Consider: get_direction_to_endpoint
The short variable name dx is described by a comment as "direction_x".
Avoid the comment with the longer variable name.
Layout
It would be more consistent to break this:
    if maze[rx][ry] == 0: continue

into 2 lines as in the rest of your code:
    if maze[rx][ry] == 0:
        continue

Simpler
There seems to be no need to multiply by one:
(1 * dx)

You also have a comment that needlessly mentions that you do so.
If there really is a good reason to do so, it would be much
more helpful to have a comment describing why you need to do
this seemingly needless action.
Convenience
It would be a convenience to the user to make the output
directory if it doesn't already exist.

get_direction works too hard. Expanding on Fe2O3 suggestion, notice that dx and dy are independent on each other. Consider
    if cx < ex: dx = 1
    elif cx == ex: dx = 0
    else: dx = -1
    # Ditto for dy

I would be tempted to say dx = numpy.sign(ex - cx).
And we still work too hard: right after dx and dy are computed, one of them is discarded. Better do the random choice before, and compute only what is necessary:
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        dx, dy = numpy.sign(ex - cx), 0
    else:
        dx, dy = 0, numpy.sign(ey - cy)
    current_position = (current_position[0] + dx, current_position[1] + dy)


while (rx := random.randint(0, width - 1), ry := random.randint(0, height - 1)):
    ....
    if count == (width * height) // 4
        break

is a very strange way to organize a loop. Better be explicit:
while count < (width * height) // 4:
    rx := random.randint(0, width - 1), ry := random.randint(0, height - 1)
    if maze[rx][ry] == 0:
        continue
    count += 1

As a side note, due to
    # If we already have a path here, skip this iteration

plenty of calls to random.randint are wasted. Better treat the mase as a one-dimensional list, fill the first quarter with zeros, fill the rest with ones, and random.shuffle it.

Just back from coffee during which I thought about what you've written as your first point. "Great minds..." :-)... Trivially, I'd tend toward producing dx = 1 / dx = -1 / else dx = 0... Then, the two conditions are the twins < and >, with == as the "black sheep" of the trio... Cheers! :-)

Appearances can deceive
The body of get_direction() is a multi-step if() ladder determining the relationship of two 2D values to return a simple tuple result to the caller. On the surface, it looks fine...
But, when the reader attempts to verify its operation, because of the sequencing, each step is quite independent of the others. The reader must envision the relationship described by two 2D points, and what would be an appropriate "shift" in order to get closer to the maze exit.
As a contrarian, I oppose @toolic's suggestion to "use longer variable names" (instead of short names and comments). In fact, I believe the OP has done a good job of giving meaningful names to important, long-lived variables, and used reasonable 'throw-away' names for variables with limited scope and duration. Verbosity does not clarify.
For example, current_X vs cX:
In use, the reader's eyes must sweep across the 8 characters of "current" (ensuring there's no misspelling or other discrete difference).
In the limited scope of their use, the reader can easily and quickly distinguish c? from e? ("current" from "end") and easily distinguish the X from Y. Don't "bury" the significant details in a wad of chaff, especially when one comment alerts the reader to the "shorthand" variables' names and purposes.
Sadly, these two observations have collided in get_direction(). This function's (unnecessarily) long-ish local variable names obscure that the 7th return() values might not be quite right.
Remedy: There are 9 possible combinations, so separate those into 3+3+3 conditionals. Determine if the current point is too high, or too low, or just right, then go on to determine if it is too far left, too far right, or just right.
Allow the reader to evaluate 1 dimension, then the 3 possibilities of the other dimension. (Think "major" vs "minor" dimensions.) Don't require up to 9 separate and independent evaluations of the two data points (with an evaluation of whether-or-not the returned value is correct, too.)
Here's a small example:
    cX, cY = current # VERY terse names used
    eX, eY = end

    if cX < eX: # currently to the left of the exit?
        if cY <  eY: return (1,  1) # Right Down
        if cY == eY: return (1,  0) # Right
        else:        return (1, -1) # Right Up
    ...


It's often the case that repetitive, tedious blocks of code are the snug lairs where hard-to-find bugs reside. Make code, especially "easy code", actually earn your trust.

Vertical or horizontal?
There's a bit of a mental struggle within.
Years of experience condition a reader to associate 'x' with a horizontal dimension, and 'y' being the vertical dimension. Years of experience with coding condition a reader with "row major (column minor)" being the most efficient access to memory representing a 2D array.
While it can go either way, for this reader, it would be less challenging if the tuples used in this code were regarded (and components named) as (row, col) instead of (x, y). This maps directly to 2D array references such as maze[row][col]...
Just something for the OP to think about (so that I don't have to.)

Late addition:
@vnp has, in the meanwhile, suggested an improvement on the one bit of example code in this answer. I agree with that insight.
I don't write Python, but have uncovered the following (single line) "stacked ternary" operation that points the way toward reducing the line count of the program:
result = "Positive" if x > 0 else "Negative" if x < 0 else "Zero"
This is fluid as the two conditions are the matching pair < and >. Altering this to provide the integer values required is left as an exercise.
After this function has shrunk to only a few lines of code, I'd propose that it be renamed propose_next() as the caller (currently) selects (randomly) one of the two values of the tuple to apply to the current location.

This looks good overall. I'll try not to repeat other answers, sorry if something is still duplicated.
I've got a couple of "major" notes that indeed raised my eyebrows, and then several suggestions for better maintainability.
First, of all,
BUG
    if current_x > end_x and current_y < end_y: # Left Down
        return (0, 1)

is incorrect - that should probably read return (-1, 1) instead.
This provokes a second comment:
Unnecessary optimization? Or missed opportunity?
Current get_direction implementation is annoyingly verbose. There are 8 conditional branches, and we're supposed to manually verify all 9 possible paths. Doable? Sure. Necessary? Perhaps not.
I propose another approach (copy type hints from your impl if you wish, of course, I'll omit them for brevity - typing in browser isn't the most convenient thing to do):
def get_direction(current, end):
    return (_sign(end[0] - current[0]), _sign(end[1] - current[1]))

def _sign(val: int) -> int:
    if val == 0:
        return 0
    if val < 0:
        return -1
    return 1

I hope this is less error-prone now: "direction" is essentially projection of the vector difference onto the (x, y) basis.
Type bug
You promise that generate_maze returns a 2D list of int. Great, but...
    # Set the start point to 'S'
    maze[start[0]][start[1]] = 'S'
    # Set the end point to 'E'
    maze[end_position[0]][end_position[1]] = 'E'

Please run mypy on your code if you use type hints. Those are intended both for humans and for tools, and tools are obviously better at spotting trivial bugs.
Strange while
This:
    while (rx := random.randint(0, width - 1), ry := random.randint(0, height - 1)):

requires quite a lot of mental efforts. This makes a tuple, which is always true, for the sole purpose of assigning two variable. So this is a while True: loop with some decorations and a break inside. Let's rewrite this:
    count = 0
    max_blanks = (width * height) // 4
    while count <= max_blanks:
        # rx: random_x , ry: random_y
        rx = random.randint(0, width - 1)
        ry = random.randint(0, height - 1)
        # If we already have a path here, skip this iteration
        if maze[rx][ry] == 0:
            continue
        maze[rx][ry] = 0
        count += 1

This is the end of a semi-critical section, everything below is more style-ish.
if/else vs or
end_position = end if end else (width - 1, height - 1)

This is fine. But x if x else y can be also spelled x or y - slightly shorter. Since your type hint indicates tuple[int, int] | None, the only falsey value is None and you're fine without if x is None "proper" check.
Verbosity
def print_maze(maze: list[list[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Prints a maze for debugging purposes.

    Parameters
    ----------
    maze - Generated maze to print.

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    for row in maze:
        print(row)

Ough. Unless you're writing a library with an autogenerated documentation (say, using sphinx), please avoid such verbosity:
def print_maze(maze: list[list[int]]) -> None:
    """Print a maze for debugging purposes."""
    print(*maze, sep="\n")

You may want to keep the loop instead and print ",".join(map(str, row)) or smth like that as default list printing may be suboptimal for human readers.
Yes, that simple. And prescribe, do not describe: first sentence of the docstring should be prescriptive ("Do X", not "Does X"), as PEP257 tells us. Same note applies to write_to_file.
Imagine e.g. mypy using this convention for every public function. The codebase currently contains ~150K lines of python code (mypy + mypyc, excluding scripts, infra and even some tests AFAIC). In your post docstrings occupy 58 out of 147 lines - about one third. That'd mean writing approx. 50K lines of documentation, most of which is essentially pointless: returns None takes 3 lines of your docstrings and is already represented by -> None 7-char type hint. That's too much for a human to scroll through - my screen will be occupied by this text instead of one more related function body.
Note I'm not arguing against docstrings: they are helpful and important. But, unless an autogenerated doc system is used, they shouldn't be mandatory for every function. When a name is descriptive, name of function + name of argument + type hints often contain exactly the same information as a docstring would, but in much terse syntax.
Type duplication
I see tuple[int, int] repeated 6 times. That would be great as e.g.
from typing import TypeAlias

Coordinates: TypeAlias = tuple[int, int]
# or (py3.12+, and I still don't like this syntax, but 
# have to show all such options)
type Coordinates = tuple[int, int]

or maybe even
from typing import NamedTuple

class Coordinates(NamedTuple):
    row: int
    col: int

(or a dataclass if you want mutability). Yes, that breaks compatibility with plain tuple passed from outside, but simplifies your code.
Consider also making list[list[int]] a Maze typealias for the same reason.
Helper reusability
write_to_file is a bit unusual: it only supports saving a maze into a single predefined file. This may be OK, but...
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Final

OUTPUT_FOLDER: Final = Path("./mazes/")

...
def write_to_file(maze: list[list[int]], destination: Path) -> None:
    """Save a maze to `destination`.

    Description
    -----------
    Writes the dimensions of the maze on the first line, then
    the generated maze.
    """
    width, height = len(maze[0]), len(maze)
    with destination.open("w") as f:
        f.write(f"{width} {height}\n")
        for row in maze:
            f.write(''.join(map(str, row)) + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    maze = generate_maze((20, 20))
    assert OUTPUT_FOLDER.is_dir(), "Output folder not found"
    write_to_file(maze, OUTPUT_FOLDER / "maze.txt")

Using strings for paths is relatively fine, but misses an opportunity to declare the real type of that thing. String is too generic, while a path represents much narrower construct.
Verbosity 2.0
While one of current answers suggested using longer variable names, I'm going to suggest the opposite. It's really difficult to parse this:
current_position = (current_position[0] + (1 * dx), current_position[1] + 0)

I think that curr and end instead of current_position and end_position is still readable - you don't track anything but positions.
Named constants and consistency
I read in the docstring of generate_maze:

A list of rows for the completed maze, 1 denoting walls and 0 denoting paths.

This parses unambiguously in my head: "returns a list of booleans disguised as integers". However, later we add S and E strings to the list, as discovered above, so it's now as wrong as it could be.
My proposal below may add significant overhead, measure if performance is critical for you.
from enum import IntEnum, unique
from typing import TypeAlias

@unique
class Cell(IntEnum):
    EMPTY = 0
    WALL = 1
    START = 2
    END = 3


Maze: TypeAlias = list[list[Cell]]

def generate_maze(
    dimension: tuple[int, int],
    start: tuple[int, int] = (0, 0),
    end: tuple[int, int] = None
) -> Maze:
    ...

Now use Cell.WALL, Cell.EMPTY, etc. throughout your code - naming things often makes your code easier to read.
